# f = open() / works in command line but not as CGI script [python]

Tags: python, cgi

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python

import htmlSplitter, htmlGlue

headerContent, mainContent, sideSetup, sideContent, footerContent = htmlSplitter.split("../htdocs/bcc/register.html")


mainContent = "<h1>This is another Test</h1>"
sideContent = "<h2>Jonathan's here!</h2>"


htmlDoc = htmlGlue.glue(headerContent, mainContent, sideSetup, sideContent, footerContent)

f = open("../bcc/doctest.html", "w")
f.write(htmlDoc)
f.close()

print("Location:../bcc/doctest.html")
print
```

this script works perfectly when I run it from the command line. However, when I run it as a CGI script, it gives me a "premature end of script headers" error. I've debugged and it's fine if I comment out the segment that opens and writes "doctest.html" (so I know that the other two modules I've included are not causing the problem). Any idea why that part of the code doesn't work as a CGI script? Is there something I should be substituting instead?

NOTE: I've done a chmod a+rw on 'doctest.html' to make sure that the script has permissions to edit.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `cgitb` to find out what is going on. `import cgitb; if DEBUG: cgitb.enable()`

Comment: got it. that's a useful tool I'm sure I probably should have known about. Thanks!

Comment: I had my relational link wrong. Working with multiple sites from the same apache server & cgi-bin gets me confused, sometimes, as I know the relationals will be different once I upload them to my company's server.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so the rest of us can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print
```

I've always declared the `Content-Type` in my python cgi scripts, it's polite.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable() # allows error tracebacks
```

[`cgitb`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) will show you a nice web based traceback if something went wrong with your script, such as any exceptions thrown.

Comment: the cgitb helped; I had a relational link error. Strangely, the open() filename is not the same path as the redirect (Location:) filename, which I find strange. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a copy/paste-error, but your shebang seems to be indented. unindent it, and try to start the script via command line on the server, using `./yourscript` (not `python yourscript`, as this is how it probably gets executed by the webserver)